# LIBMINGWEX-0.DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, mingw

Какие бы я программы я не писал, на виртуальной машине моя программа не работает. Всё из-за одной динамической библиотеки "libmingwex-0.dll", которую программа не находит. При том, если скопировать библиотеку из папки bin/ в папку с программой на виртуальной машине, всё заработает. Так что же происходит и как подключить библиотеку к программе?

P.S. Я начинающий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение, распрострайте все нужные `.dll` с вашей программой.

Но если очень хочется запихнуть все нужные `.dll` в один экзешник, то это делается флагом `-static` (почитайте про *статическую линковку*).